# Insert Results of Query(column) Into an existing table in mysql

Tags: mysql, insert

For example, there are two tables:

1. **student** (`student_id`, `student_name`);
2. **score** (`student_id`, `score1`, `score2`).

If I want to insert into **student** table the results of `query(column)` such as

```
SELECT score1+score2 FROM score
```

what should I do?

Comment: Into which field do you want it inserted? And why? Is this a one time migration, or are you planning to continue doing this on a recurring basis, in which case... that sounds messy unless you get into triggers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i understand you need to update students table with additional score, and fill this score column from score table, If this is what you want then first add new column in students table as

```
ALTER TABLE `student` ADD COLUMN `score` INT(11) NULL AFTER `student_name`;
```

then use `update` query with a join on score table

```
UPDATE student s
JOIN score sc ON s.`student_id` = sc.student_id
SET s.`score` = sc.score1 + sc.score2
```

Comment: further question:

Comment: If its different question then better to ask a new one

Comment: if the two tables are:

1. **student** (student_id, student_name);
2. **score** (student_id, subject, score1, score2).

and I want to add a new column in student table finding the average score of all subjects for each student. What can I do?

Comment: I guess it would be better to ask a new question due change in your original structure and change in requirements this answer may become invalid